# use getchar to discard all but first character using loop c code

Tags: c

I would like to find out, how to improve this function to control input and display of input for only using first character from getchar function
avoiding the rest that user might type. When the user types several characters printf prints that many times. How to correct that flaw?

```
    int checkLevelValidity(int levelOne, int levelTwo) {
        int level = 0;  //initialize to value zero (false)
        printf("Choose difficulty level: press (1) for single digit 
            or (2) for double: ");

        //get user input when level value is zero at start
        while ( level == 0 ) {       

            scanf("%d", &level);
            //if input is not an integer (false on return from scanf)
            if ( level == 0 ) {     

                printf("Enter (%d or %d): ", levelOne, levelTwo);

                getchar();
            }
            //if input is integer then check for correct level value
            //if input less than (1) or larger than (2)
            if ( ( level != 0 ) && 
                ( level < levelOne || level > levelTwo ) ) {

                printf("Enter correct level (%d or %d): ", 
                    levelOne, levelTwo);

                //reassign zero value to loop again 
                level = 0;
            }
        }
        return level;       //returns correct value of (1) or (2)
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are levelOne and levelTwo? What exactly do you expect the user to type? `scanf` is probably not the most appropriate function for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
// Loop as long as there is an error in reading 
// the level or the value of level is not right.
while ( ( scanf("%d", &level) != 1 ) ||
        ( level != levelOne ) ||
        ( level != levelTwo )
{       

   if (feof(stdin))
   {
       // Deal with EOF
   }

   // Ignore the rest of the line up to the newline.
   scanf("%*[^\n]");

   printf("Enter (%d or %d): ", levelOne, levelTwo);
}
```

Comment: This code results in an infinite loop if user types an end of file (^D in unix/mac, ^Z in Dos/Windows).  Furthermore, it does not test if user typed `1` or `2`, just that the user did not type `0`.